# Magento - Re Order Categories

Tags: magento

In the Admin Panel of Magento under the Manage Categories, I have the following:

Accessories (main heading)
   Handbags
   Swimwear
   Jewellery
   All Accessories

However, I would like the order to be:

Accessories
   All Accessories
   Handbags
   Jewellery
   Swimwear

How do I change the order?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you accept at least one answer or give input.

Answer (score 16):

Depending on whether you are talking about root or subcategories here. Subcategories is easy.

1. Click Catalog > Manage Categories
2. Click and drag up or down on the sub categories (ones below the main category) to arrange in correct order.
3. Almost most importantly - save it :).

You will need to some coding to get the root categories to adjust positions. I don't know what you are using for navigation menus, but would it be possible to use sub categories for those?